# Как добавить отступ для блоков при печати?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Не могу понять как реализовать отступы на последующих страницах при печати? Интересует как в альбомном, так и в книжном варианте? Есть идеи?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
      <div className="print-content">
          <div class="card">
            CARD NUMBER
          </div>
      </div>
```

```
.print-content {
  display: block;
  margin: 30px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.card {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 525px;
  height: 359px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.print-content {
    display: block;
    margin: 30px;
    padding: 5px;
  }
  .card {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 525px;
    height: 359px;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
  }
  @media print {
    .print-content {
        padding: 10px;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но не помогло

Comment: а что за браузер ?

Comment: chrome browser юзаю

Comment: сам проверял на хроме - отступы есть. Может просто стили не сохранил ?:)

Comment: Ну что ж я. Все сохранил я)